# Remove header and blank row from the results of a SUM, GROUP BY query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a two column table where one column is some sort of key where duplicates are allowed and the other column includes amounts.

I then have the following formula somewhere else on the sheet:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "SELECT SUM(A) GROUP BY B")
```

The results of that query begin with 'sum', then a blank line, then the summed values:

[image: spreadsheet with sum]

How can I modify the existing formula so that I do not have the 'sum' header and the blank line (if I can at all)? I want to avoid using multiple cells to create the desired affect and I want to avoid scripting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To suppress the header, end the query string with `label sum(A) ''`.

The blank spot below the header comes up because the column B, besides the letters a,b,c, also contains a bunch of blank cells, which form a group of their own. Since you don't want them, add the clause `where B<>''`.

End result:

```
=query(A1:B, "select sum(A) where B<>'' group by B label sum(A) ''")
```

(Case doesn't matter: I prefer lowercase because more text fits into the same horizontal space.)

Comment: Thanks. That works great. For some reason though, when I did `<> ''` for certain columns in my real project, I kept getting `N/A` (no results). The columns I tried were the amount column, a date column, and a derived `MONTH` column (which is actually how I will be grouping). So I just used a column that will always be a non-empty description.

Comment: Try `B not null` instead of `B <> ''`.