# Query Import Range returns two rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I've been using =Query(Importrange( functions for quite a while now and something I can't figure out is why the import is returning with two rows.  Here's the formula I've been using:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1kYg-7Jqpe9RRE_rpRMUQy3wcY15RVN_Atx5aP43cLBI","Per 1!A1:Q100"),"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col2 contains '"&A9&"'")`

It always returns with the header row from the import AND the data it's supposed to import.  How do I get it to stop importing the header row?

Comment: Welcome to WebApps StackExchange. You're getting the header because you're using the QUERY command. The official documentation is a bit light-on in this regard, but this topic might help [Google SpreadSheet Query: Can I remove column header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26867775/1330560)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove header and blank row from the results of a SUM, GROUP BY query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88373/remove-header-and-blank-row-from-the-results-of-a-sum-group-by-query)

Comment: Specify the QUERY function headers parameter as 0 to omit headers.  `QUERY(data, query, [headers])` Query function help page: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en  ```If omitted or set to -1, the value is guessed based on the content of data.```